# How to protect ADC input from reverse polarity?

Tags: adc

I want to use an [AD7124-8 ADC](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7124-8.pdf) in a project:

I was wondering how to protect the analogue inputs from reverse polarity. According to the datasheet inputs can tolerate at most 0.05/0.1 volts of reverse voltage:

[image: Maximum Tolerable Analogue Input Voltage]

Thus, clamp diodes cannot offer any protection here. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

P.S. Reverse voltage is at most 15 volts.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't an external reverse polarity protection diode do the trick here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The datasheet is a bit misleading here: it describes the voltage limits you've quoted as "absolute", but it's as opposed to *differential* rather than the safety limits of the device.

The safety limits are provided on page 13, and we see that the analog inputs can tolerate up to 0.3 V below ground, and can tolerate an injection current of up to 10 mA. This almost certainly means there are internal clamping diodes, so you only need to add a current-limiting resistor between the external input and the ADC.

The larger the resistor the better, but at least 15 V / 10 mA = 1.5 kΩ is necessary. Keep in mind, though, that the resistor effectively adds to the impedance of your source, so bandwidth will be affected.

Perhaps more important than the bandwidth, the ADC inputs have a leakage current, which will be multiplied by the source impedance to produce a voltage error. Since the ADC is differential, the error is based on the difference between the leakage currents, typically 1.5 nA in full-power mode. With 1.5 kΩ, this produces an error of over 2 microvolts.

Comment: The resistor shouldn't be too large because of the input current (approximately 1 nA).

Comment: Good point—I hadn't looked at the input current specs. I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. This completely resolved the issue. I don't know how I missed the absolute Maximum ratings on p. 13 :) .  BTW, bandwidth isn't an issue here. I'm reading low frequency signals.

Answer (score 2):

See p.13 of the datasheet, Absolute Maximum Ratings. The max reverse voltage is -0.3V, so a Shottky diode should suffice. Perhaps the circuit already has clamp diodes an this is where the value comes from, although I don't see any mention of them in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed the -0.3 v part.